# Shell Error: value too great for base (error token is "09")

Tags: bash, shell, unix

The Question already exists in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049822/bash-error-value-too-great-for-base-error-token-is-09), but it didn't solve my problem.
The function **getDate** calculate number of days based on 3 parameters.

But I always get this error: `value too great for base (error token is "09")` line 7 `val= ..`

```
function getDate (){
    d=$1
    m=$2
    y=$3
    m=$(((m+9) % 12))
    y=$((y - m/10))
    val=$((365*y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + (m*306 + 5)/10 + ( d - 1 )))
    return $val
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because because of **leading `0` shell treats `09` as an octal value** and obviously `09` is an invalid octal value.