# First day of the previous month using Shell scripting

Tags: shell

I am trying to get the first day of the previous month using shell script using the below command in the format 2017-05-01

Firstday=`date -d "-1 month -$(($(date +%d)-1)) days" +"%Y-%m-%d"`

But it is throwing the below error.

value too great for base (error token is "09").

Can anyone help please?

Comment: the issue is related to 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21049822/bash-error-value-too-great-for-base-error-token-is-09   

But not able to fit in to my requirement.

Comment: START_DATE=`date -d "-1 month -$(expr $(date +%d) - 1) days" +"%Y-%m-%d"`

Got It :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%e` to pad the day with a space, rather than a zero:

```
firstday=$(date -d "-1 month -$(( $(date +%e) - 1 )) days")
```

The leading space has no effect on the expansion.