# shifting the file name with bash adding a constant number

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, radix

I have some files named:

```
0001.jpg
0002.jpg
...
0050.jpg
```

I need to increment that number by 35, so that I obtain:

```
0036.jpg
0037.jpg
...
0085.jpg
```

I thought of trying the following:

```sh
for i in {0001..0050}; do
  mv -n $i $((i+35)) 
done
```

However I get the error `bash: 0008: value too great for base (error token is "0008")`.  I'm not sure I understand what the `base` means here or how to get around it.  I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777597/value-too-great-for-base-error-token-is-08).  Although it explains the octal error, it is not immediately clear how it helps to iterate with a shifted index.

Comment: Btw. I suggest to count from 0050 to 0001 because the ranges overlap.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value too great for base (error token is "08")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24777597/608639), [Value too great for base (error token is “09”)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21049822/608639), etc.

Comment: @jww those two solutions are essentially "$((10#$hour + 1))", but, although hearing about octals numers was informative and interesting, it was not the solution I was looking for.

Comment: @Massagran - Interesting, thanks. Why did you accept the answer that fixed your octal counting?

Comment: @jww it was the first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that bash arithmetic treats numbers starting with `0` as octal number and only 0-7 digits are allowed in octal system. You can prefix `10#` before number to tell bash to accept given number as base 10 number and computer your sum.

You may use:

```
for i in {0010..0001}.jpg; do
   f="${i%.jpg}"
   echo mv "$i $(printf '%04d' $((10#$f + 10#35))).jog"
done
```

Once you're satisfied with output, remove `echo` before `mv`.

```
mv 0010.jpg 0045.jog
mv 0009.jpg 0044.jog
mv 0008.jpg 0043.jog
mv 0007.jpg 0042.jog
mv 0006.jpg 0041.jog
mv 0005.jpg 0040.jog
mv 0004.jpg 0039.jog
mv 0003.jpg 0038.jog
mv 0002.jpg 0037.jog
mv 0001.jpg 0036.jog
```

Comment: Not sure if the first move should be from 0001.jpg to 0036.jpg because 0036.jpg will already exist.

Answer (score 2):

bash, like C, interprets a number that starts with a zero as an octal number when used inside an arithmetic expansion.  This is the standard behavior for a POSIX sh.  Since "8" is not a valid value inside an octal number, you get an error.

Since what you want is to count from 1 to 50 and add 35, and then format it as a number, you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in $(seq 50 -1 1)
do
    mv -n $(printf '%04d.jpg' $i) $(printf '%04d.jpg' $((i + 35)))
done
```

This iterates from 50 to 1, and formats each number using the `printf` program.  This is, incidentally, also portable POSIX sh in addition to working in bash.

Answer (score 2):

Eventually I went with:

```sh
for i in {50..1};
do
    old=$(printf '%04d.jpg' $i)
    new=$(printf '%04d.jpg' $((i + 34)))
    mv -i -- "$old" "$new"  #-i to avoid overwritting
done
```

Answer (score 1):

@Massagran almost your own solution:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in {50..1}; do
  printf -v old_filename '%04d.jpg' $i
  printf -v new_filename '%04d.jpg' $((i + 35))
  [[ -f $old_filename ]] && mv --no-clobber -- "$old_filename" "$new_filename"
done
```

How it differs and improve your answer:

- Rather than capturing the output of `printf` into a variable by running `printf` in a sub-shell, it uses the `-v` option, so `printf` outputs directly into the variable.
- Before performing the rename, it test that the old filename exist and is an actual file.
- To prevent overwriting an existing file, it uses the `--no-clobber` rather than the `--interactive` option.